# Need help with riddle

Tags: riddle

I am useful, not beautiful.

Years ago I was huge, but now I can sit in a desk.

I do not think, but I can help you do your school work.

New models of me can play music.

What am I?

Answer (score 4):

Probably it is

> a computer.

I am useful, not beautiful.

> They're not known for being particularly aesthetic, though some are better than others.

Years ago I was huge, but now I can sit in a desk.

> Old computers filled whole rooms. Now a laptop can easily fit in a desk drawer.

I do not think, but I can help you do your school work.

> Computers only run programs, they don't actually think. But much schoolwork today is not only facilitated by a computer, it actually requires one.

New models of me can play music.

> Sure!

This riddle feels like it's from the late 1980s or 1990s, though, where

> "not beautiful" and "sit in a desk" (perhaps "sit ON a desk" in the original?) and "new models ... can play music" feel more relevant. Desktop PCs were definitely a thing, were squat and ugly, and had only recently gotten to the point where they could play music.

Answer (score 2):

It can be

> A watch or alarm clock.

Because

> Alarm clock is useful, but few people love it, especially in the early morning.

> Many years ago, the watch was very bulky, now there are miniature models that can be put on a table.

Moreover

> The watch has a mechanism that helps to look time and distribute it and in addition to mechanical cod, modern alarms can play a melody.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a

> calculator?

I am useful, not beautiful.

> They are tools, not art.

Years ago I was huge, but now I can sit in a desk.

> They were a lot larger originally, but technological advancement has made them smaller.

I do not think, but I can help you do your school work.

> They are useful for rote mathematical computation.

New models of me can play music.

> They can. Some people have even played songs on them.